# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen „Stockhaus“ und „Zuchthaus“?

Tags: meaning, difference, etymology, synonym

„Stockhaus“ und „Zuchthaus“ bezeichnen jeweils eine bestimmte Art Gefängnis.

---

Das DWDS nennt für „Zuchthaus“ die Bedeutung: “Strafanstalt für Häftlinge mit **strafverschärfendem** Arrest“.<sup>[1](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Zuchthaus)</sup>
Das Grimm’sche Wörterbuch meint,<sup>[2](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=GZ08727#XGZ08727)</sup> das Zuchthaus hat ursprünglich nicht der Strafe, sondern der Zucht (im Sinne von Erziehung) gedient:

> darnach in ein zuchthausz gethan,
>   da sie kein stund solt müssig gan,
>   da sie in zweyer jaren frist
>   schreiben und lesen hatt gewist

Schließlich hat das Wort die Bedeutung „Gefängnis“ angenommen, doch unterteilte man Zuchthäuser (nämlich *criminalzuchthäuser* und *polizeyzuchthäuser*) weiter „in das mildere besserungshaus, und in das **strengere** zuchthaus“; es wird auch der Ausdruck „schärfere“ Strafanstalt genannt.

---

Als Bedeutung des Wortes „Stockhaus“ nennt das DWDS (historisch) „Gefängnis, Kerker“,<sup>[3](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Stockhaus)</sup> der Duden (online) mag das Wort gar nicht kennen.
Wikipedia hat nicht mal einen vollständigen Satz für das Stockhaus übrig: „in Abgrenzung zu Zuchthaus ein Gefängnis für Schwerverbrecher“.<sup>[4](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stockhaus)</sup>
Wieder weiß der Grimm mehr:<sup>[5](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=GS48081#XGS48081)</sup>

> eigentlich 'haus, in welchem sich der stock für die gefangenen
>   befindet' […], dann allgemein 'das
>   gefängnisz'; […]
>   im gegensatz zum zuchthaus diente es hauptsächlich den schweren
>   verbrechern; die gefangenenräume darin sind meist dunkel […]
>   (vgl. auch die in diesem zusammenhang zu
>   suchenden adject. stockdunkel und stockfinster)

Das Wiktionary ist auch nicht hilfreich:
Stockhaus: „historisch: Gefängnis für Schwerverbrecher“<sup>[6](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Stockhaus)</sup>
Zuchthaus: „veraltend: Gefängnis für Häftlinge mit einem verschärften Strafvollzug“<sup>[7](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Zuchthaus)</sup>

---

Das Zuchthaus ist strafverschärfend, aber das Stockhaus ist in Abgrenzung zum Zuchthaus ein Gefängnis für Schwerverbrecher?
Also werden Schwerverbrecher nicht strafverschärfend verwahrt?

**Was ist der Unterschied zwischen den beiden Ausdrücken?**

Comment: I don't think it's useful to try and find relationships between dictionaries that have 150 years of language development between them. Especially the meaning of "Zuchthaus" has significantly changed over time and now basically takes the place of "Stockhaus" 150 years ago.

Comment: @tofro Ja, ich habe bloß versucht, alle nützlichen Informationen einzubeziehen, die ich zur Hand hatte. Wenn du meinst, Zuchthaus ist das neue Stockhaus, dann könntest du daraus eine Antwort machen.

Comment: @Philipp Ohne tofro zu widersprechen: Au contraire: Hab versucht mir den Zedler für alle Okccasiones zu memorieren. Handel, Wandel, und gegenwärtiger Usus: bin ganz begeistert, tadelloser Ansatz.Historischer Sprachgebrauch ohne historische Bezüge etc.? – As is: great Q!

Comment: Den Begriff Zuchthaus kennt eigentlich jeder, auch wenn offiziell schon lange von JVAs die Rede ist und im Alltagsgebrauch 'Gefängnis, Knast' und weitere dominieren. Stockhaus habe ich noch nicht gehört und dürfte den meisten unbekannt sein. Huberts Antwort mit dem Stock hat mir erst den Begriff eröffnet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Der Stock war eine Holzfessel, die den Gefangenen um den Hals und die Hände gelegt wurde, Oft war sie sogar ortsfest, so dass der Gefangene nicht fliehen konnte. Siehe [Stock (Fessel) auf Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stock_(Fessel)).

Das Haus, in dem die Gefangenen mit einem Stock gefesselt waren, war das Stockhaus. Es war eine Strafanstalt.

Die Zellen in einem Stockhaus waren dunkel, und daraus entstand später dann auch das Wort *»stockdunkel«* als Verstärkung des Wortes *»dunkel«.* Später wurde das Präfix *»stock-«* auch vor andere Adjektive gesetzt um sie zu verstärken (*stockbetrunken, stocktaub, ...*)

In einem Zuchthaus gab es keinen Stock, es diente ursprünglich der Zucht (im Sinn von *Erziehung*) und war ursprünglich keine Strafanstalt.

Comment: Im Rückblick auf die eigene Ausbildung: hätt ich wissen können, wenn nicht müssen. Im Hinblick auf die Frage und den eigenen Vergessens- oder Wissensstand: Absolut augenöffnend. Kudos.

Answer (score 4):

Im Laufe der Zeit hat sich das Zuchthaus wohl verändert, wie die beiden folgenden Zitate aus Wikipedia zeigen:

Im deutschen Wikipedia-Artikel zu [Zuchthaus](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zuchthaus) steht dazu zunächst:

> Das Zuchthaus diente ursprünglich nicht als Strafanstalt im eigentlichen Sinne, da es sich bei den Insassen nicht primär um Kriminelle handelte. Man verstand das Zuchthaus damals als soziale Einrichtung, die arbeitsunwillige Menschen „therapieren“ und wieder in die Gesellschaft zurückführen sollte.

Später heißt es dann:

> Nach dem Ende des Absolutismus gab es eine langsame Mäßigungsbewegung. Nach und nach wurde ein Rechtssystem umgesetzt, und die Bedingungen, unter denen Menschen in solche Einrichtungen verbannt wurden, wurden verschärft. So entstand aus dem Zuchthaus allmählich eine Strafanstalt im eigentlichen Sinne.

Insbesondere in der Anfangszeit des Zuchthauses existierte wohl die Abgrenzung zum Stockhaus, wobei schwere Straftaten eher ins Stockhaus geführt haben.

Answer (score 0):

[Adelung](http://www.zeno.org/nid/20000456365) steuert bei:

> Das Stockhaus, des -es, plur. die -häuser, ein Haus oder Gebäude, in
> welchem sich Ein oder mehrere Gefängnisse zur Verwahrung der
> Gefangenen befinden. Von Stock, ein Klotz, ingleichen Gefängniß. S.
> auch Stockmeister.

Das würde mehr auf eine Bauform schließen lassen, hilft aber zur Abgrenzung zu Zuchthaus nicht weiter.

Answer (score -2):

In Karlsruhe gab es um 1818 in der Linkenheimerthor-Straße Nr. 7 (der heutigen Hans-Thoma-Straße 7) ein Gebäude, das als Militärstrafhaus gebaut worden war.
(Quelle: Mangler: Fünfzig Skizzen zur Geschichte der Stadt Karlsruhe, S. 56)

Im Andressbuch von 1818 hatte dieses Haus die Bezeichnung "Stockhaus".
(Quelle: Adressbuch der Stadt Karlsruhe von 1818)

Comment: Das beantwortet die Frage nicht.